# mvn exec:exec and mvn exec:java difference

Tags: java, maven

I have gone through the documentation at @ [codehaus exec-maven-plugin usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html). I understand that the exec:java allows the user to execute the java program, in the same VM as they state. I am a newbie in maven and my aim is to understand the difference between `mvn exec:exec` and `mvn exec:java` so that I can apply them better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use mvn exec:java when you are working with java classes and want to run them in your JVM (with all project dependencies as classpath), whilst mvn exec:exec allows you to run any executable (like shell script to do some cleanup or windows batch file), not only the java ones.

Answer (score 4):

The [main page of the documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) gives a short overview:

> exec:exec execute programs and Java programs in a separate process.
>
> exec:java execute Java programs in the same VM.